# regexp help for a scoreboard

Tags: javascript, regex

Im trying to build a scoreboard where you cannot input a name if it has special characters or if it contains spaces.

Tried something like this

```
const name = nameInput.value;
const test = /[A-z 0-9 ^\s]/.test(name)
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: It would help if you tagged this with the appropriate programming language. You should also provide a minimal, complete example and explain precisely what "doesn't work" means (see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: You know. I honestly dont understand why i keep coming back here. This place seems to be choke full of "individuals" hellbent on having draconic rulebooks than focusing on helping people.

Comment: Might have botched it when i didnt include the javascript tag (although im fairly certain regex char sets work the same for any programming language) but if you need an example for "no input if name has special character or space" then i really cant help you.

Comment: What is the value of `nameInput.value;` ?

Comment: Is it defined as well ?

Comment: Anything a user inputs into an input bracket. The value then needs to be compared to a regex charset to ensure it does not have special characters or spaces.

Comment: @hanshenrik looks like it might but it doesnt mention spaces. Will check when i get back to my laptop. Thank u

Answer (score 0):

^ to match start and $ to match end,

```
/^[a-z0-9]+$/i.test("test"); => true
/^[a-z0-9]+$/i.test("test9"); => true
/^[a-z0-9]+$/i.test("test9 "); => false
/^[a-z0-9]+$/i.test("testæøå"); => false
```

ofc if you need unicode support, it gets a whole lot harder, not sure how to solve that.. (sure you could change the regex to `/^[a-z0-9æøå]+$/iu` to support Norwegian unicode characters, but that still leaves out Swedish unicode characters, you could add them but that would still leave out Chinese characters, and so on...)

- i could make a unicode alnum table, but that would be huge, and would probably take a couple of days..

Comment: You should be able to use Unicode character classes using `\p`

Answer (score 0):

If you're ok with with an underscore (_), this should also do:

```
/^\w+$/.test("abiAcd9")
```

`\w` matches `[A-Za-z0-9_]`